# How to make a .dart file with an @HtmlImport directive part of a library

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

Given that the library directive can be the only directive in a file, how can I make a component .dart file that is part of a library also contain the @HtmlImport directive?

For example, given the following:

**.dart**

```dart
part of epimss_shared.components;

@CustomTag('blue-theme')
class BlueTheme extends PolymerElement {
  String topic = '';

  @observable String lb50 = lightBlue_50;
  @observable String lb100 = lightBlue_100;
  @observable String lb200 = lightBlue_200;
  @observable String lb700 = lightBlue_700;

  BlueTheme.created() : super.created();

  @published
  String get width => readValue(#width);
  set width(String value) => writeValue(#width, value);

  @override
  void attached() {
    super.attached();
    topic = this.dataset['topic'];
  }
}
```

**.html**

```dart
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link href='../../../../packages/core_elements/core_style.html' rel='import' >

<polymer-element name='blue-theme'>

  <template>
    <core-style id='blue-theme'>
      :host {}
      <!-- BLUE THEME -->   
      .lblue50 {
        background-color: {{lb50}};
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        border-radius: 10px;
        width: {{width}};
      }   

      .lblue100 {
        background-color: {{lb100}};
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        border-radius: 10px;
      }  

      .lblue200 {
        background-color: {{lb200}};
        border-radius: 10px;
        padding-left: 2px;
        padding-right: 2px;
        padding-top: 4px; 
      }  

      .lblue700 {
        background-color: {{lb700}};
        border-radius: 10px;
      }
    </core-style>
  </template>

  <script type='application/dart' src='blue_theme.dart'></script>
</polymer-element>
```

If I should add ..

```dart
@HtmlImport('blue_theme.html')
library epimss_shared.component.dart;
```

to the .dart src, errors are suggested that that the library directive can be the only directive on the page.

I thought that with the new HtmlImport I could now finally put .dart and .html file in a library the same way I can do it with .dart files alone, but this seems incorrect.

Is there a way to accomplish what I am trying to do? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding it to the library instead of the part?

Comment: No. I have now tried your suggestion, but a question arises. The library directive would be the first library entry - library | epimss_shared.components; |. When I put the reference | @HtmlImport('blue-theme') | does this implicitly says that the blue-theme is now part of the mentioned library? From the given usage, the HtmlImport is usually followed by its reference library. Is this correct or incorrect.

Comment: This just says when you import the library the transformer adds an HTML import for the components HTML so you or users of your component doesn't have to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

When you import the library the transformer adds an HTML import declared by `@HtmlImport(...)` for the components HTML so you or users of your component don't have to do it manually.

See also [Dart. How to use @HtmlImport on the example of Polymer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708183)