# How to check Custom Element is registered?

Tags: html, dart, dart-polymer

Some method creates new instance of my custom element (created with polymer) and attaches it on page. But I want to check is Element registered before add it and print error to console in bad case. I mean what if I forgot import component html declaration:

```
<!--I forgot write it in my HTML file -->
<!--<link rel="import" href="packages/visualytik/vis_starter.html">-->
```

So, in case when I forgot import I want to print error in console.

I know one tricky method:

```
import 'my_custom_component.dart';
Element component = new Element.tag('my-custom-component');
bool registered = component is MyCustomComponent;
```

But it's hard method because we should create component first and have to import `MyCustomComponent.dart` in dart file. Can I check it in other way? Something like:

```
document.isRegistered('my-custom-component');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update3**
You can also use the new `@HtmlImport` annotation. If you import the class, then you can be sure you also have imported the HTML of the element. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/29710355/217408

**Update2**
See [Hunting down unregistered elements](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/debugging.html#unregistered)

**Update**
Use a custom constructor in your elements class and do the registration there but only if it wasn't done already.

```
class MyCustomComponent extends ... {
  bool _isRegistered;
  bool get isRegistered => _isRegistered;
  factory MyCustomComponent() {
    if(!isRegistered) {
      registerElement();
      _isRegistered = true;
    }
    return new Element.tag('my-custom-element');
  }
}
```

and then create new instances like

```
new MyCustomElement();
```

and you can always be sure the element is registered only once (but you always need to use this constructor of course).

**Original**

If you register your elements by calling `document.RegisterElement()` yourself instead of relying on Polymer for example, you need to hold a reference to the constructor reference `document.RegisterElement()` returns, otherwise you won't be able to create an instance of the element.
Therefore you just need to check if you already have a reference to the constructor. See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/registerElement