# Is it possible to let pub only serve the web/ directory using IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, dart

This is a question to Dart users of IDEA or WebStorm.

When using the Run or Debug functions, IDEA runs pub serve and serves your project to the Dartium browser. However, it serves the whole project directory, so that the index file is at `http://localhost:port/MyProject/web/index.html`.

Is it possible to configure pub to only serve the web directory?

The reason why this is a problem is because I try to use PolymerJS elements and they seem to somehow request files using absolute paths.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issueMobile/WEB-14047
but this never caused me any troubles. There is probably something wrong with your imports. Do you use the new `@HtmlImport` this should help reduce errors.

Comment: Do you have a reference on `@HtmlImport`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708183/dart-how-to-use-htmlimport-on-the-example-of-polymer