# Dart 'SdkAnalysisContext' is not loaded

Tags: dart, polymer

I want update polymer app from version "^0.16.4" to '1.0.0-rc.5'. I have some lines in pubspec.yaml:

```
environment:
  sdk: '>=1.12.0 <2.0.0'

dependencies:
 bwu_datagrid:
   git:
     url: 'https://github.com/bwu-dart/bwu_datagrid'
     ref: 'polymer1'

 polymer: '1.0.0-rc.5'
 polymer_interop: '^1.0.0-rc.3'
 reflectable: '>=0.3.2 <0.3.4'
 web_components: '^0.12.0'

dependency_overrides:
 code_transformers: '^0.4.0'
 reflectable:'^0.5.0'
 redstone: '0.5.21+1'
 quiver: '>=0.21.3 <0.22.0'
 analyzer:'0.27.1'
 polymer:'^1.0.0-rc.5'
 args: '>=0.12.1 <0.14.0'
```

But when I run pub get, I get errors:

```
Error on line 24, column 5 of ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/10.10.3.91%588080/initialize-0.6.1+2/pubspec.yaml: Error loading transformer: 'package:code_transformers/src/dart_sdk.dart': malformed type: line 128 pos 39: type 'SdkAnalysisContext' is not loaded
  final AnalysisContext context = new SdkAnalysisContext();
                                      ^
type error.
    $include: '**/*_test.dart'
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error on line 23, column 5 of ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/10.10.3.91%588080/polymer_interop-1.0.0-rc.7/pubspec.yaml: Error loading transformer: 'package:code_transformers/src/dart_sdk.dart': malformed type: line 128 pos 39: type 'SdkAnalysisContext' is not loaded
  final AnalysisContext context = new SdkAnalysisContext();
                                      ^
type error.
    $include: test/**_test{.*,}.html
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error on line 26, column 5 of ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/10.10.3.91%588080/web_components-0.12.0+4/pubspec.yaml: Error loading transformer: 'package:code_transformers/src/dart_sdk.dart': malformed type: line 128 pos 39: type 'SdkAnalysisContext' is not loaded
  final AnalysisContext context = new SdkAnalysisContext();
                                      ^
type error.
    $include: '**/*_test.html'
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Error on line 19, column 3 of ../../../.pub-cache/hosted/10.10.3.91%588080/polymer-1.0.0-rc.5/pubspec.yaml: Error loading transformer: 'package:code_transformers/src/dart_sdk.dart': malformed type: line 128 pos 39: type 'SdkAnalysisContext' is not loaded
  final AnalysisContext context = new SdkAnalysisContext();
                                      ^
type error.
- web_components
```

dart --version
**Dart VM version: 1.13.2 (Tue Jan  5 06:49:57 2016) on "linux_x64"**

pub --version
**Pub 1.13.2**

Maybe some advice on how it can be solved?

transformer section in pubspec.yaml:

```
transformers:
 - polymer:
     entry_points:
       - web/index.html

 - $dart2js:
     minify: true
     commandLineOptions:
       - --trust-type-annotations
       - --trust-primitives
       - --enable-experimental-mirrors
```

pub serve print that:

```
[Info from Reflectable on web_tt_client|web/index.bootstrap.initialize.dart]:
Ignoring entry point  that does not include the class `Reflectable`.
Build completed successfully
```

and in dartium console:

```
Uncaught Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Reflectable has not been initialized. Did you forget to add the main file to the reflectable transformer's entry_points in pubspec.yaml?
```

spa.dart file:

```
library spa;

import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'package:web_tt_client/routers/routers.dart';

//Components
import 'package:web_tt_client/components/page_view/page_view.dart';

main() async {
  await initPolymer();
  await prepareViewElement();
  await prepareRouters();
}
```

index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
    <script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.7/firebase.js'></script>
    <!-- JSON-Schema library tv4-->
    <script src="packages/web_tt_client/js/tv4/tv4.min.js"></script>

    <script src="packages/web_components/webcomponents.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>

    <page-view></page-view>

    <br>
    <div id="html_log" style="white-space: nowrap;"></div>
    <script type="application/dart" src="spa.dart"></script>
    <script src="packages/browser/dart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pub update. Newer version of packages avalible for:

```
grinder 0.6.6+3 (0.8.0+2 available)
http_multi_server 1.3.2 (2.0.0 available)
http_parser 0.0.2+8 (2.0.0 available)
postgresql 0.2.14 (0.3.3 available)
redstone 0.5.21+1 (0.6.0+1 available)
redstone_mapper 0.1.13 (0.2.0-beta.1+1 available)
redstone_mapper_pg 0.1.1 (0.2.0-beta.2+2 available)
shelf 0.5.7 (0.6.4+3 available)
test 0.12.3+9 (0.12.7 available)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you stick to an old Dart and Polymer version? Current Polymer is `1.0.0-rc.15`. Dart stable is available in 1.14.2

Comment: Now, I just want to run bwu_datagrid with any newer polymer.

Comment: Try updating to the newest versions, at least Polymer. Simply change `polymer: '1.0.0-rc.5'` to `polymer: '^1.0.0-rc.5'`. You can also use `bwu_datagrid: '^0.1.0-dev.0'` instead of a Git dependency.

Comment: Now I try use dart sdk 1.14.2 with polymer 1.0.0-rc.15 version, and i get `Build error:
Transform WebComponents on web_tt_client|web/index.html threw error: Class 'LibraryElementImpl' has no instance getter 'node'.`

Comment: I try use pub update, and now when i use pub serve I get `Build completed successfully` and message: `Ignoring entry point  that does not include the class Reflectable.` And in dartium console: `Bad state: Reflectable has not been initialized. Did you forget to add the main file to the reflectable transformer's entry_points in pubspec.yaml?` But in pubspec.yaml I add main file to polymer entry point transformers.

Comment: You need to add a transformer section that points to your entry page https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart#building-and-deploying

Comment: `pubspec.yaml` looks good. Can you please also post `index.html` and `main.dart` (or `index.dart`)

Comment: I think you should use `@HtmlImport(...)` instead of `<link rel="import" href="packages/web_tt_client/components/page_view/page_view.html">` for all Polymer elements. Not sure if Polymer 1.0.x still works with that kind of imports or what needs to be condsidered so it does. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29708183/dart-how-to-use-htmlimport-on-the-example-of-polymer

Comment: I changed it for now, and error remained

Comment: That's not exactly how HtmlImport works `@HtmlImport('packages/web_tt_client/components/page_view/page_view.html')` You import Polymer elements by importing the Dart file with normal Dart imports. Only in the Polymer elements Dart file you import the elements HTML using `@HtmlImport('page_view.html')` and you don't need a Dart script tag in the elements HTML anymore.

Comment: Now i do it right? [gist](https://gist.github.com/Rasarts/1f0c80c14224c06274a6) I get also trouble: `line 10, column 1 of lib/polymer_micro.html: Failed to inline HTML import: Could not find asset polymer_interop|lib/polymer_micro.html`. And in console Internal error: `Dart_Invoke expects library argument 'target' to be loaded.`

Comment: Yup, looks good. Hard to tell. Can you run `pub upgrade` from the command line and check for which packages the output says a newer version is available?

Comment: Thanks. None of them matter :-/ I'm out of ideas. I guess we need to wait for Jake.

Comment: Ok. I will wait and hope.

Comment: I changed pubspec.yaml dependency_overrides section. And now all works great. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interesting! Didn't expect that to solve the problem. You can answer your own question. I think it would be good to do that. After some cool down period you can also accept your own answer and then the question isn't listed as unanswered anymore. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change pubspec.yaml dependency_overrides section, can solve it.

```
dependency_overrides:
 code_transformers: '^0.4.0'
 reflectable:'^0.5.0'
 redstone: '0.5.21+1'
 quiver: '>=0.21.3 <0.22.0'
 analyzer:'0.27.1'
 polymer:'^1.0.0-rc.5'
 args: '>=0.12.1 <0.14.0'
```